# frequent screen blackouts followed by system crashes on MacBook Pro Retina OS X 10.10.5

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, crash, kernel-panic, gpu

I'm working away on my MBP when suddenly the screen blacks out and the operating system crashes instantly or shortly afterwards. The blackouts occur while using different programs, although I have a feeling that they are more frequent with graphic intensive software like Photoshop. After restart, the system is back to normal but it's not long until the next black out obliterates my unsaved work.

Below is one of the crash reports for the experts here that can actually make sense of them. I'm only gleaning from the gibberish that the crash probably occurred because of the GPU, Intel HD Graphics 4000 1024 MB in my case, suddenly becoming afraid of seeing my face and deciding to black out. Or does "panic" mean something else in this case ;-)

What's going on here? Does anybody have more of a clue than me?

(System: MacBook Pro Retina 15'', 10.10.5, CPU 2.3 GHZ Intel Core i7, RAM 8GB, Intel HD Graphics 4000 1024 MB, 2012 model)

```
Anonymous UUID:       95707A62-8F44-800D-0E29-BEF2DFD7A38B

Fri Sep 30 14:05:08 2016

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff7f84317c1b): "GPU Panic: [<None>] 5 0 a0 d9 9 8 0 3 : NVRM[0/1:0:0]: Read Error 0x00000100: CFG 0xffffffff 0xffffffff 0xffffffff, BAR0 0x104000000 0xffffff8112f9d000 0x0e7150a2, D0, P1/4\n"@/SourceCache/AppleGraphicsControl/AppleGraphicsControl-3.10.25/src/AppleMuxControl/kext/GPUPanic.cpp:127
Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff811290aa50 : 0xffffff800152ae01 
0xffffff811290aad0 : 0xffffff7f84317c1b 
0xffffff811290abb0 : 0xffffff7f82275ea6 
0xffffff811290ac70 : 0xffffff7f8234390d 
0xffffff811290acb0 : 0xffffff7f82343978 
0xffffff811290ad30 : 0xffffff7f8257fbcc 
0xffffff811290add0 : 0xffffff7f825974df 
0xffffff811290ae10 : 0xffffff7f823bdaf6 
0xffffff811290ae40 : 0xffffff7f823bda81 
0xffffff811290ae70 : 0xffffff7f824cd184 
0xffffff811290aea0 : 0xffffff7f824cef1b 
0xffffff811290af30 : 0xffffff7f824cf3ff 
0xffffff811290afa0 : 0xffffff7f8228b0db 
0xffffff811290aff0 : 0xffffff7f824d392f 
0xffffff811290b150 : 0xffffff7f824d3d3a 
0xffffff811290b1e0 : 0xffffff7f8237b73e 
0xffffff811290b3b0 : 0xffffff7f8237b354 
0xffffff811290b3f0 : 0xffffff7f8238b5a0 
0xffffff811290b450 : 0xffffff7f8238c21d 
0xffffff811290b510 : 0xffffff7f8225f4b4 
0xffffff811290b530 : 0xffffff7f8225fe3c 
0xffffff811290b570 : 0xffffff7f8225f2fd 
0xffffff811290b610 : 0xffffff7f82251135 
0xffffff811290b6c0 : 0xffffff7f8227a6f9 
0xffffff811290b8c0 : 0xffffff7f8227b815 
0xffffff811290b9a0 : 0xffffff7f824223ca 
0xffffff811290b9f0 : 0xffffff7f82422bcf 
0xffffff811290baa0 : 0xffffff7f82416bc3 
0xffffff811290bc60 : 0xffffff7f82220f53 
0xffffff811290bcf0 : 0xffffff7f82209f94 
0xffffff811290bd70 : 0xffffff7f8220cf8a 
0xffffff811290bdb0 : 0xffffff7f8220c806 
0xffffff811290be20 : 0xffffff7f821d1639 
0xffffff811290be60 : 0xffffff7f821d0792 
0xffffff811290be90 : 0xffffff7f821cc8e3 
0xffffff811290bef0 : 0xffffff8001ad5bbd 
0xffffff811290bf40 : 0xffffff8001ad3a2d 
0xffffff811290bf80 : 0xffffff8001ad3b26 
0xffffff811290bfb0 : 0xffffff8001611867 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.4.1)[7372D580-6DDE-3457-B043-49B8447FC9D2]@0xffffff7f82208000->0xffffff7f82217fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[8922721D-5517-3883-BD3A-57422D0244A0]@0xffffff7f821c1000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[1571E932-87CE-3EDF-9A81-19694AFEA29E]@0xffffff7f81d31000
         com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl(3.10.25)[752C63EA-73E8-39BC-8225-3A97D0C403BF]@0xffffff7f84309000->0xffffff7f8431cfff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl(3.10.25)[3DC2F93F-5197-3B16-8975-0142E7A0474B]@0xffffff7f84301000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[70E2B65E-A91A-3522-A1A0-79FD63EABB4C]@0xffffff7f82b5e000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[1571E932-87CE-3EDF-9A81-19694AFEA29E]@0xffffff7f81d31000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[8922721D-5517-3883-BD3A-57422D0244A0]@0xffffff7f821c1000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert(1.1.0)[65E3187E-949B-36E9-BA33-1B13ABB0581A]@0xffffff7f84304000
         com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman(10.0.4)[95736EED-9154-3CBF-B639-6038E7128035]@0xffffff7f8221f000->0xffffff7f824a0fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[1571E932-87CE-3EDF-9A81-19694AFEA29E]@0xffffff7f81d31000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.4.1)[7372D580-6DDE-3457-B043-49B8447FC9D2]@0xffffff7f82208000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[8922721D-5517-3883-BD3A-57422D0244A0]@0xffffff7f821c1000
            dependency: com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl(3.10.25)[DFDCFB7E-74E4-397E-AA6F-6ECFC41D5649]@0xffffff7f82218000
         com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAGK100Hal(10.0.4)[7B99C2A0-B505-3A0A-9BDE-494FD7CB3E2D]@0xffffff7f824ac000->0xffffff7f8265bfff
            dependency: com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman(10.0.4)[95736EED-9154-3CBF-B639-6038E7128035]@0xffffff7f8221f000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[1571E932-87CE-3EDF-9A81-19694AFEA29E]@0xffffff7f81d31000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
14F1912

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 14.5.0: Mon Aug 29 21:14:16 PDT 2016; root:xnu-2782.50.6~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: FE3619E6-270B-34A6-BBD7-BED74EC32693
Kernel slide:     0x0000000001200000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8001400000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8001300000
System model name: MacBookPro10,1 (Mac-C3EC7CD22292981F)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 12986805448097
last loaded kext at 8102829368371: com.apple.filesystems.smbfs  3.0.2 (addr 0xffffff7f84461000, size 389120)
last unloaded kext at 12396207921328: com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIUpAdapter 2.0.2 (addr 0xffffff7f84417000, size 49152)
loaded kexts:
com.avast.AvastFileShield   3.0.0
com.avast.PacketForwarder   2.1
com.techsmith.TACC  1.0.2
com.Cycling74.driver.Soundflower    1.5.2
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 3.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.19.6
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.2.0d4
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   272.18.3
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.3.6f3
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.GeForce   10.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000Graphics   10.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   272.18.3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.7d0
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.10.25
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.12
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferCapri 10.0.6
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.3.6f3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 2.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 240.2
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.BootCache 36
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    705.4.2
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.7.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.6.5
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   930.37.3
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   705.4.14
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXHCI   710.4.11
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 218.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   161
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   218.0.0
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAGK100Hal    10.0.4
com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman  10.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   97.4
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 272.18.3
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.15
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.10.25
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.13d1
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.9.1d7
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    156.17
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.10.25
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.3.6f3
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.3.6f3
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 272.18.3
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 272.18.3
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   203.3
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 245.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  705.4.9
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    471.30.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    3.1.7
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 4.2.2
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   730.60
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 720.4.4
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 398
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  3.1
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
Model: MacBookPro10,1, BootROM MBP101.00EE.B0A, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.3 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.3f32
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Intel HD Graphics 4000, Built-In
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, PCIe, 1024 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333531533642465238432D50422020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333531533642465238432D50422020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xEF), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.15.166.24.3)
Bluetooth: Version 4.3.6f3 16238, 3 services, 18 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Thunderbolt Ethernet, Ethernet, en3
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM256E, 251 GB
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 23.4
```

Answer (score 1):

Your MacBook Pro has two graphics cards.  One is integrated with the motherboard ( the Intel HD Graphics 4000) and one is a separate desecrate card that is connected to the motherboard (the NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M.)

The Intel "card" is a low power graphics controller that is good for most display tasks, while the NVIDIA card is a more powerful card that gets used by more demanding applications (like Photoshop, VMware, etc)

It looks to me like you are suffering from a GPU panic on the NVIDIA card, perhaps when the computer switches from one card to the other - or due to the card overheating or hitting a bad memory segment.  I am not excellent at reading these crash reports.

I recommend you take your machine back to the folks at Apple who can tell you what is required to swap out the offending graphics card.

Comment: My MBP really does seem to be a lemon. This is the 2nd hardware problem in a few years. :-(

Comment: How do you know that it's the NVIDIA not say the internal Intel card or the shared RAM?